# Transparent (opacity) image from top 0% to bottom 100% in CSS

Tags: image, css, opacity, css-shapes

Its possible do it? Just in CSS, like this picture, so I mean if I put on `<div>` tag background image, I need it to be transparent from top to bottom.

I want to create something similar to the image below:

[image]

Comment: Not really a possibility with CSS AFAIK. In fact, I don't think it's possible to reproduce that exactly at all (especially if the top of the img is **actually** transparent)...at least not without a lot of unnecessary extra HTML & CSS. Sometimes an image is the best way.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. I'll try to do it differently. :)

Comment: If you just need the 'transparency' to be from white to the image...it's a little easier...would that do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As other answers state : making the image transparent from top to bottom is not possible in CSS.

**BUT**

If you have a solid background color (or similar) you can simulate that transparency whith CSS3 inset box-shadows.
For the image white overlay and the semi transparent black rectangle. In the following demo, I used pseudo elements to minimize *HTML* markup.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3L2TV/)**

Output :

[image: Simulated transparency over image with CSS3 inset box shadows]

*HTML :*

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
.image{
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    margin:50px auto;
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-8.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 850px 500px -500px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 850px 500px -500px #fff;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 850px 500px -500px #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 850px 500px -500px #fff;
}
.image:before,.image:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:5%;
    opacity:0.5;
}
.image:before{
    top:0;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 850px 500px -500px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 850px 500px -500px #000;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 850px 500px -500px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 850px 500px -500px #000;
}
.image:after{
    width:20%;
    height:10%;
    top:100%;
    background:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can do this in webkit! Mozilla allows for SVG masks, but I won't get into that. Zero support in IE.

**Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kZ8F/)**

**HTML:**

```html
<div>
    <img src="http:/www.fillmurray.com/300/200"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  -webkit-mask-size: 300px 200px;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, 
  color-stop(0.00,  rgba(0,0,0,0)),
  color-stop(1.00,  rgba(0,0,0,1)));
}
```

Reference: http://caniuse.com/css-masks

Comment: This answer could benefit from an update since all modern browsers do support (`-webkit-`)`mask-image: linear-gradient()` nowadays. https://jsfiddle.net/19ps6vry/

Answer (score 3):

I [made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wg8B/) for you to use. You have to use gradients with rgba. This is not supported in all browsers so you might want to manipulate the image instead. This however is the only way to do it in CSS.

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/meta/6/6d/Wikipedia_wordmark_1x.png" />
        <div class="whatever"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin:0px;
}

img {
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
}

.whatever {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        color-stop(0, #ff00ff),
        color-stop(1, rgba(0,0,0,0))
    );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff00ff 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff00ff 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff00ff 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff00ff 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff00ff 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    top:-34px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **`background`** CSS property with **`linear-gradient`** value set by your self for your requeirement.

#### CSS

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3H9RB/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to reproduce that exactly at all (especially if the top of the img is actually transparent). If you just need the 'transparency' to be from white to the image...it's a little easier..

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/8sCMK/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="imgwrap">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-2.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #bada55;
}

.wrapper {
    height:240px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 25px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    background-color: white;
    padding:8px;
}

.imgwrap {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.imgwrap:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1) 35%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    z-index:1;

}
```

Comment: Same difference. you can't make something transparent that isn't transparent to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Overlay a gradient div over the image with position absolute and z-index:

CSS

```
section{
    margin:0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px;
    width: 300px;
    display:block;
    height: auto;
    position:relative;
}
section #overlay{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(255,255,255,1)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:2;    
}
section #imgContainer{
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;

}
section #imgContainer img{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;

}
```

HTML

```
  <section>
        <div id="overlay">
        </div>
        <div id="imgContainer">
           <img src="" />
        </div>
    </section>
```