# How to achieve a seamless opacity decrease?

Tags: javascript, css

I have multiple elements, which are not in a container, and I can't put them into a container neither. For example:

```
<div class="code-line">Code line 1</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 2</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 3</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 4</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 5</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 6</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 7</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 8</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 9</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 10</div>
```

With some minimal css:

```
.code-line {
  background-color: #e9dfba;
}
```

How could I achieve that the opacity is decreased on the last 4-5 lines and it has a continuous effect. Something similar like this:
[image]

About line 12, it gets a little less visible, and it proceeds to the last line it is barely visisble.

The best I could do, is to set the opacity on the lines (0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2), but it is not seamless, because the horizontal lines (the difference in opacity between the elements) can be seen (it is barely visible on the picture, but it is definitely more visible on the screen):

[image]

Comment: maybe you get ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781216/transparent-opacity-image-from-top-0-to-bottom-100-in-css

Comment: They seem to be in a container in your screenshot, why do you say they're not? And if indeed they're not, can we assume all of: their positions will be top to bottom with one element per line, a fixed number of elements, no "foreign" elements in between two targeted elements, no wrapping of any of the targeted elements? Not saying I'd have a solution if all of these can indeed be assumed, but if they can't then it definitely makes things a lot harder, and you will need to define what should happen in such a case.

Comment: because they are not. This is for an Obsidian plugin. All the lines, regardless of what line it is (code line or not) are just lines. They are in a main container, yes, but the code block lines are not in a separate container. no foreign elements between the targeted elements, but the elements have child elements(line number, and syntax highlight requires it)

Comment: Please provide an actual sample of the markup, with the parent container and all that creates trouble.

Comment: Seconding Kaiido's request. We need to see the parent wrapper, at least (even if it is `<body>`) and ideally the descendant elements you reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using opacity, which applies evenly across the entire element, you should use a gradient mask.

The neatest way to superimpose a gradient on top of something is with an `::after` pseudo-element. Your elements may not be in a specific container, but all elements are contained in the `<body>` element, so you could apply the gradient at that level. If you want the text to fade into the background, then make the gradient colour match the background colour, or if you want it all to fade to white, then make it a white gradient.

```css
body {
  background-color: #e9dfba;
  position: relative;
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(233,223,186,0) 50%, rgba(233,223,186,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>Code line 1</div>
<div>Code line 2</div>
<div>Code line 3</div>
<div>Code line 4</div>
<div>Code line 5</div>
<div>Code line 6</div>
<div>Code line 7</div>
<div>Code line 8</div>
<div>Code line 9</div>
<div>Code line 10</div>
```

If there is really no container element you can use, and you only want to style the individual items, then you could just split the gradient into five and apply a section of it to each of the last five items.

```css
.d1 {
  background-color: #e9dfba;
  position: relative;
}

.d1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.d1:nth-last-child(6)::after {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(233,223,186,0) 0%, rgba(233,223,186,0.2) 100%);
}

.d1:nth-last-child(5)::after {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(233,223,186,0.2) 0%, rgba(233,223,186,0.4) 100%);
}

.d1:nth-last-child(4)::after {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(233,223,186,0.4) 0%, rgba(233,223,186,0.6) 100%);
}

.d1:nth-last-child(3)::after {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(233,223,186,0.6) 0%, rgba(233,223,186,0.8) 100%);
}

.d1:nth-last-child(2)::after {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(233,223,186,0.8) 0%, rgba(233,223,186,1) 100%);
}

/*
NOTE that the position that you use with :nth-child(n) or :nth-last-child(n)
refers to a child element’s position relative to ALL children of its parent
element, NOT just the children which match first part the selector (.d1 in
this case).

In this example, the ten .d1 <div>s are children of the <body>, but the last
child of the body is an empty <script> element. You can see this in your
browser inspector. So the last .d1 <div> is the second-last child of the
<body>; that’s why we use .d1:nth-last-child(2) to target it.
*/
```

```html
<div class="d1">Code line 1</div>
<div class="d1">Code line 2</div>
<div class="d1">Code line 3</div>
<div class="d1">Code line 4</div>
<div class="d1">Code line 5</div>
<div class="d1">Code line 6</div>
<div class="d1">Code line 7</div>
<div class="d1">Code line 8</div>
<div class="d1">Code line 9</div>
<div class="d1">Code line 10</div>
```

Comment: OP said, "*which are not in a container, and I can't put them into a container neither.*".

Comment: Okay, missed that, but even if the elements don’t have a specific container, all elements are contained by `<body>`. I have updated my snippet to remove the specific container and use body as the container instead.

Comment: But then the question is how to affect only these elements, they certainly have something else in their body too where they won't want this effect.

Comment: I have added second snippet to demonstrate how it could be done without referencing any container.

Comment: second option worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

For those browsers which support :has (currently all the main ones except Firefox which requires a flag to be set) you can find the last element.

Then you can overlay it with a linear-gradient which goes from transparent to white and sits in its before pseudo element with negative top margin.

That way the last element will be obscured and the amount of transparency can be controlled by setting the height of the pseudo element.

```html
<div class="code-line">Code line 1</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 2</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 3</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 4</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 5</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 6</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 7</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 8</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 9</div>
<div class="code-line">Code line 10</div>
<style>
  .code-line {
    background-color: #e9dfba;
  }
  
  .code-line:not(:has(+ .code-line))::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, #e9dfba);
    margin-top: -4em;
    z-index: 1;
  }
</style>
```

Note, if you want the background color to fade as well then set the linear gradient to go to white rather than #e9dfba

Comment: Since you'd need JS to set the height why not use JS to get the last element?

Comment: You don't actually need JS to set the height - but I agree you could get a more accurate result if you did - but it wasn't specified exactly how much obscurity was required, just some.

Comment: How come you don't need JS? If you know how many elements there are before, you don't need this `:has()` trick either, but I doubt we can assume. a fixed number, nor a fixed height, but anyway, this question is just too unclear for a proper answer that'd be useful to anyone else.

Comment: Agreed for absolute accuracy use JS, but the question was how to obscure the bottom few in a decreasing manner, without  the 'few' being defined so this does that. But if it's not useful to the OP I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image):

```css
main {
  background-color: #e9dfba;
}

.code {
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 50%, transparent 100%);
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 50%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="code">
    <div class="code-line">Code line 1</div>
    <div class="code-line">Code line 2</div>
    <div class="code-line">Code line 3</div>
    <div class="code-line">Code line 4</div>
    <div class="code-line">Code line 5</div>
    <div class="code-line">Code line 6</div>
    <div class="code-line">Code line 7</div>
    <div class="code-line">Code line 8</div>
    <div class="code-line">Code line 9</div>
    <div class="code-line">Code line 10</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Check the browser coverage on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=mask-image)

Comment: The other way around please, -webkit-  always before standards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use js to dynamically adjust the opacity of the lines to create a fading effect. This will not be as seamless as the gradient overlay but its a workaround given that you cant put elements into a container.

```
// Get code lines into array
const codeLines = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.code-line'));

// Num of lines you want to fade - the last 5 lines
const fadeLines = 5;

// Calc the decrement step for opacity
const decrementStep = 1 / fadeLines;

// Loop through the last fadeLines elements and set opacity
for (let i = 0; i < fadeLines; i++) {
  const opacity = 1 - (i + 1) * decrementStep;
  codeLines[codeLines.length - 1 - i].style.opacity = opacity;
}
```

Ofc you can adjust the `fadeLines` and `decrementStep` to control how many lines are affected and how quickly they fade out.